# Yii2 Mailer isn't actually sending emails

Tags: yii2, html-email, swiftmailer

I followed a *Yii2* tutorial for *sending e-mails with attachment*,
(See the link below if you need)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5pebmTUQjs&index=21&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF

And it worked on a level that the system reads the email info and the attachment that I want to send, and saves the info and attachment link in the db.

But when I tried to send emails to a real recipient and changed the mailer config, then tried to create a new email 
there was a problem:

**Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Setting unknown property: Swift_MailTransport::host**

Here is the config for mailer:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
                    'host' => 'smtp.live.com',
                    'username' => 'username@live.com',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'port' => '587',
                    'encryption' => 'tls',
                   ]
],
```

And here is the actionCreate part of the EmailsController:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Emails();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $model->attachment= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'attachment');

            if ($model->attachment)
            {
                $time=time();
                $model->attachment->saveAs ('attachments/' .$time.'.' .$model->attachment->extension);
                $model->attachment='attachments/'.$time.'.'.$model->attachment->extension;
            }

            if ($model->attachment)
            {
                $value= Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom (['sharqpress@hotmail.com'=>'Al-Sharq Printing Press'])
                ->setTo ($model->reciever_email)
                ->setSubject ($model->subject)
                ->setHtmlBody ($model->content)
                ->attach ($model->attachment)
                ->send();
            }

            else
            {
                $value= Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom (['sharqpress@hotmail.com'=>'Al-Sharq Printing Press'])
                ->setTo ($model->reciever_email)
                ->setSubject ($model->subject)
                ->setHtmlBody ($model->content)
                ->send();
            }

            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id]);}
            else
                return $this -> render('create',['model'=>$model,]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration needs additional class:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport', // <-- here
        'host' => 'smtp.live.com',
        'username' => 'username@live.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
    ]
],
```

Comment: I saw many references and there wasn't another class included. And if it really needs another class, what is it or what does it stand for? See the link of documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html

Comment: As a default `Swift_MailTransport` is used. This is Transport class for SwiftMailer as stated [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html). You can see this in the [Mailer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/blob/master/Mailer.php) class of yii2-swiftmailer extension.